# what's the difference between tag-based and Port-based VLAN and which one is better?

Tags: switch, vlan

[image]

what's the difference between tag-based and Port-based VLAN and which one is better ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are really asking about the difference between trunk interfaces and access interfaces.

An access interface is an interface where you connect and end-device (PC, printer, etc.). Most end-devices do not understand tagged frames. The switch will only send frames for a particular VLAN through an access interface, and it assumes any frames received on the interface are for the VLAN configured on the interface.

Trunk interfaces carry frames for multiple VLANs. In order for a device on the other end of the trunk link to separate the frames into the correct VLANs, you must tag the frames (possibly except frames for a single VLAN, which would be the native VLAN for that trunk).

Some end-devices may be configured to understand tagged frames and use a trunk. This is done by creating virtual interfaces, one for each VLAN.

---

**Edit:**

Tag-based VLANs are the industry standard 802.1Q VLANs, while the port-based VLANs are more akin to Private VLANs. If you need to ask this question, you probably want tag-based VLANs, but we really do not have enough information about the final objective to give you an answer.

The manual is pretty clear about the difference:

> VLAN Mode:
>
> Tag-based:
>
> This is the default setting.
>
> Tag-based VLAN identifies its member by VID. This is 
>   quite different from port-based VLAN. If there are any more 
>   rules in ingress filtering list or egress filtering list, the
>   packet will be screened with more filtering criteria to 
>   determine if it can be forwarded.The switch supports supplement
>   of 802.1q.
>
> Each tag-based VLAN you built up must be assigned VLAN name 
>   and VLAN ID. Valid VLAN ID is 1-4094. User can create total up to 256
>   Tag VLAN groups.
>
> Port-based:
>
> Port-based VLAN is defined by port. Any packet coming in or
>   outgoing from any one port of a port-based VLAN will be accepted. No
>   filtering criterion applies in port-based VLAN. The only criterion is
>   the physical port  you connect to.  For example, for a port-based VLAN
>   named PVLAN-1 contains port members Port 1&2&3&4.  If you are on the
>   port 1, you can communicate with port 2&3&4. If you are on the port 5,
>   then you cannot talk to them. Each  port-based VLAN you built up must
>   be assigned a group name. This switch can  support up to maximal 26
>   port-based VLAN groups.

Comment: I'm a student in network administration . this year i have a project about divide my university network in VLANs , i did not understand how to divide it because the switches are old "LevelOne GSW-2690" it have the two options tag-based and port-based VLAN . could you help me in this ?

Comment: It is pretty clearly explained in the manual. What else do you need to know?

Comment: after making multiple port on a vlan how could I make inter VLANs connection (trunk in cisco ) ??

Comment: In a Cisco switch, you would use the `switchport mode trunk` command. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: i'm not using a Cisco switch i'm using "LevelOne GSW-2690" it don't have trunk mode that's the my problem , what should i do for links between switches . (sorry for my bad english )

Comment: You just asked about Cisco. The manual for this switch is pretty clear. What, specifically, don't you understand?

Comment: I don't speak english that's why it's hard to understand . Ok understood .
can you help me with a free software that can scan the network and map it cause i need to know each port RJ45 in which switch it's relited to put it in the right VLAN

Comment: From my interpretation of the manual, if a port is a member of a "Tag-based VLAN", it will receive and forward tagged frames as a trunk port does. It also appears that all untagged frames are assigned a PVID for all ports. If you want to change the VLAN tag applied to ingress untagged traffic then you specify that in the PVID section. Then if you want to send untagged egress traffic on a port, you select the port in the "Untag" section of "Tag-based VLAN" configuration. You can hook up a PC and install Wireshark to capture the packets to see whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

In this context the tag-based VLANs appear to be the standard implementation of the VLANs which conforms to the [IEEE 802.1Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q) standard whereby traffic can be segregated to multiple virtual broadcast domains and this segregation can be preserved across multiple switches using a trunk line that carries traffic belonging to multiple VLANs. That is to say port 1 on a switch can be assigned VLAN10, port 2 can be assigned VLAN20 and port 3 can be configured as a trunk carrying both VLAN10 and VLAN20 to some other switch where VLAN10 and VLAN20 traffic will be able to reach their respective ports.

Port-based VLANs appears to be a feature that makes it possible to isolate a group of physical ports within a single switch, but this is "crude" way to isolate traffic because the traffic from multiple groups so isolated can't be sent to some other switch by means of a single trunk line. Think about this feature as a way to break down a single switch into multiple dumb switches. You could have ports 1, 2, 3 to be part of "VLAN1" and ports 4, 5, 6 part of "VLAN2", but if you wanted to extend these "VLANs" to some other switch you would have to run two independent cables between these switches - one for each so called "VLAN". It is barely VLAN, because "V" stands for "virtual" and in this implementation it is not so virtual anymore.

Comment: They're just different paths to the same end. "tag-based" allows editing port membership at the VLAN level - i.e. vlan 10 has these members. "port-based" allows editing vlan membership at the port level - i.e. port 1 is part of these vlans. Most vendors only do one of the two. Both methods have their pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

Using VLANs, you can split or partition a physical switch into multiple, logical ones - each VLAN represents its own, closed broadcast domain and switching/bridging is only performed within that VLAN.

The simplest form of that is a *port-based* VLAN: you assign ports to a specific VLAN and these ports can only communicate between themselves (on the data link layer/L2). If you have more than one switch, each VLAN requires a dedicated link between switches. Communication between VLANs requires forwarding on the network layer/L3 by a router.

Since multiple links between switches may waste ports, *tagged* VLANs were invented: an explicit tag is added to each frame as is exits the switch, unambiguously identifying the VLAN that the frame belongs to for the receiving switch. That way, a *VLAN trunk* can be formed, transporting frames from multiple VLANs between two switches over a single physical link.

These methods can be combined, so a VLAN trunk port may have a 'native' or untagged VLAN that it associates frames with that are not carrying an explicit tag.